# android, webview, javascript injection

Tags: javascript, android, webview, code-injection

I'd like to call a JavaScript function out of Java (Android).

The following source code works fine for me ([source](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2008/09/using-webviews.html)).

```
 /**
  * This is not called on the UI thread. Post a runnable to invoke
  * loadUrl on the UI thread.
  */
  public void clickOnAndroid() {
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:wave()");
      }
    });
  }
```

My problem now is to use a parameter for the JavaScript function.

Let's assume I've got some XML (just like AJAX somehow).

I need to escape it just like the iPhone / Objective-C command `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` does.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code:

```
String js_str = "Your JS Code";

webview.loadUrl("javascript:"+js_str);
```